# how to show a known matrix radius inequality

Tags: matrices

Let $A, B, C$ be symmetric positive definite matrices, define $R(A,B)=\max\{\rho(A^{-1}B), \rho(B^{-1}A) \}$, where $\rho(\cdot)$
means the spectral radius. Is it obvious $R(A,C)\le R(A,B)R(B,C)$? How to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  First, recall that
$$
\rho(AB) \;\leq\; \rho(A)\rho(B)
$$
for any symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$.  Then
\begin{align*}
R(A,B) R(B,C) \;&=\; \max\{\rho(A^{-1}B),\rho(B^{-1}A)\} \max\{\rho(B^{-1}C),\rho(C^{-1}B)\} \\
                &\geq\; \max\{\rho(A^{-1}B)\rho(B^{-1}C),\rho(B^{-1}A)\rho(C^{-1}B)\} \\
                &\geq\; \max\{\rho(A^{-1}C),\rho(C^{-1}A)\} \\
&=\; R(A,C).
\end{align*}